# MSSQL: How do I compare passwords? PWDCOMPARE() returns 0

Tags: sql-server, encryption

So i get the encrypted password with:

```
SELECT 
    password, 
    cast(password as binary)
FROM SYSLOGINS where name = 'user'
```

**password:** `ꗩ�ꎒ䵰᠗賦弱ꊮ㟥탑琥ꡍ뛰肓貝쫼㢐祫喀虀ꆓﱲ䈼䛂鄊⏻讨䎊༗䒶햅翲`
**binary:** `0x0200E9A56BD992F3704D1718E68C315FAEA2E848A1D025744DA8D0B69380`

When I compare the plain password with the binary, the result is 0.

```
SELECT 
    pwdcompare(N'plain_password', cast(password as binary)) -- returns 0
FROM SYSLOGINS where name = 'user'
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

I checked the various encryption methods and I believe that `PWDENCRYPT()` is used in this case, instead of `HASHBYTES()`.

Comment: whatever method is being used to encrypt/hash password needs to be applied to the password entered and then compare stored password to password entered after being hashed/encrypted.

Comment: @xQbert How should the comparison look like? Is it `pwdcompare(pwdencrypt(N'plain_password'), cast(password as binary))` ? Is my mistake there?

Comment: why the cast to binary? Docs state: `PWDCOMPARE ( 'clear_text_password'  
   , password_hash   
   [ , version ] ) `

Comment: @xQbert I assumed it should be like that because the `pwdencrypt()` returns binary, as well as `hashbytes()`. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Varbinary <> binary https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017  and [pwencrypt returns varbinary(128)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/pwdencrypt-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I tried `cast(password as varbinary)`, the comparison still returns 0.

Comment: [This Wordpress post](https://gauravlal.wordpress.com/2015/06/09/pwdcompare-and-pwdencrypt-hidden-functions-of-t-sql/) has a working example to flollow. What is the datatype for "Password" in syslogins?

Comment: PWDCOMPARE cannot be used with the passwords of contained database users. There is no contained database equivalent.  You're not attempting to do this with contained db users right?  [Doc link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/pwdcompare-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  I'm thinking so given [syslogins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syslogins-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)...  (Sorry I didn't even look at the table name to start with...)

Comment: I am trying to check the passwords for the users in `database/security/users`. The datatype of the password column obtained with `exec sp_columns SYSLOGINS` is `sysname`.